# sorting of strings using qsort

Tags: c, data-structures

I am trying to sort an array of strings using stdlib qsort. Could anyone point to me the step I am missing.

```
int compare(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    const char *ia = (const char *)a;
    const char *ib = (const char *)b;
    return strcmp(ia, ib);
}

//utility to print strings
void print_strs(char name[][10],int len){

    int i=0;
    len = 5;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        printf("%s \n",name[i]);
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char names[5][10] = {"norma","daniel","carla","bob","adelle"};
    int size1 = sizeof(names[0]);
    int s2 = sizeof(names)/size1;
    print_strs(names,5);
    qsort(names,s2,sizeof(char),compare);
    printf("\n==================\n");
    print_strs(names,5);
    return 0;
}
```

Following are the issues in the output :

1.unsorted strings
 2.first string of the array is incorrect(Norma printed as amnor).

```
norma
daniel
carla
bob
adelle
==================
amnor
daniel
carla
bob
adelle
```

Comment: Make up your mind about whether you're trying to sort an array of `char *`s (as your comparison function is defined) or an array of `char[10]`s (as the array is declared) or an array of `char`s (according to the size you passed to qsort).

Comment: `sizeof(char)` --> `size1`

Answer (score 1):

You are passing wrong `size` while calling `qsort`. You are passing `sizeof(char)` as the size of your individual element, which is wrong. In your case each individual element is a string with ten characters.

So, you can correct that by either calling `qsort` as:

```
qsort(names,s2,sizeof(char) * 10,compare);
```

Or, as you already have captured this value in `size1`, you can use that, as:

```
qsort(names,s2,size1,compare);
```