# Why does this string binary search program can't search half up the data?

Tags: c, binary-search

At first, I thought the program runs fine, but when I test to search "horse", it failed to search. And I notice the program could only search up to half of the data. Does anyone know why? 
I have added the qsort, but it still won't search the next half of the data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int compare(const void *a, const void *b){

    const char *ia = (const char *)a;
    const char *ib = (const char *)b;

    return strcmp(ia, ib);
}

int main(int argc, char argv){

    char data[10][50]={"cow", "goat", "dog", "sheep", "chicken", "duck", "bird","fish", "bee", "horse"};
    int size1 = sizeof(data[0]);
    int n = sizeof(data) / size1;
    printf("%d\n\n", n);
    int i, j;
    bool check = false;
    char key[10];
    int low = 0;
    int high = n - 1;
    int mid;
    char temp;

    for(i = 0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%s\n", data[i]);
    }

    qsort(data, n, size1, compare);
    printf("=============\n\n");

    for(i = 0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%s\n", data[i]);
    }
    system("pause");
    printf("Search: "); scanf("%s", &key);
    fflush(stdin);

    while(low<=high){
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if(strcmp(key,data[mid])==0){
            printf("Data Found ! on index - %d\n", mid);
            break;
        } else if(strcmp(key,data[mid])<0){
            low = mid + 1;
        }else {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
    }

    if(low > high){
        printf("Data not found");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Binary searching is for sorted data. Yours is clearly not sorted.

Comment: I'm about to add that questions, how do you make a string data sorted ? Is it by the ASCII number ?

Comment: also don't compare the `key` with the `data[mid]` twice.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/38689982/1679849

Comment: @r3mainer Yes, that help to sort the data, but the search still doesn't works

Comment: @Ackdari if the compare only needed once, how do I compare the key < data[mid] then?

Comment: @Christian by storing the compare result in a variable.

Comment: @Ackdari I'm sorry, I don't know what to store in the variable. Do i suppose to store the result of key == data[mid]  ??

Answer (score 2):

with `qsort` you can sort your array of string and also here `else if (strcmp(key, data[mid]) < 0)` as I showed in below code should be `>`. otherwise your search won't work.

```
static int myCompare(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    return strcmp(*(const char**)a, *(const char**)b);
}

int main()
{
    char* data [] = { 
        "cow", "goat", "dog", "sheep", "chicken", "duck", "bird","fish", "bee", "horse" 
    };
    int n = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]);
    int i;

    qsort(data, n, sizeof(const char*), myCompare);
    char key[10];
    int low = 0;
    int high = n - 1;
    int mid;
    char temp;

    scanf("%s", key);
    fflush(stdin);

    while (low <= high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        int a = strcmp(key, data[mid]);
        if (a == 0) {
            printf("Data Found ! on index - %d\n", mid);
            break;
        }
        else if (a > 0) {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
        else { // or only else(no special need for else if
            high = mid - 1;
        }
    }

    if (low > high) {
        printf("Data not found");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whaat ! Thanks a lot, wait,  so (strcmp(a,b) < 0) doesn't read as " a < b ???

Comment: @ChristianHalim feel free , no need for thanks ,but if this answer was helpful accept the answer.

Comment: @ChristianHalim it does, so`strcmp(key, data[mid]) > 0` means the key is greater than the mid value, so you want the next search to start above  the midpoint, `low = mid + `

Comment: @ChristianHalim actually in any other kind of binary search(not for strings) this would be like here and no  '(strcmp(a,b) < 0)' is like this ' a < b'  here.

Comment: @ChristianHalim pay attention to order of `key`  and  `data[mid]`. in comparing.

Comment: You do the comparison at worst 3 times per loop, why not saving it in a variable?

Comment: Also for what is the variable `i` declared?

Answer (score 1):

As the comments above, binary searching is for sorted data. Yours is clearly not sorted. So first of all, you have to sort your data. There are a lot of algorithm for sorting the data, but the code below, i use the quick sort that will help you understand your searching algorithm also.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

void swap(char ** a, char ** b) { 
    char * t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}


/* This function takes last element as pivot, places 
   the pivot element at its correct position in sorted 
    array, and places all smaller (smaller than pivot) 
   to left of pivot and all greater elements to right 
   of pivot */
int partition (char ** arr, int low, int high) { 
    char * pivot = arr[high];    // pivot 
    int i = (low - 1);  // Index of smaller element 

    for (int j = low; j <= high- 1; j++) { 
        // If current element is smaller than the pivot 
        if (strcmp(arr[j],pivot) < 0) { 
            i++;    // increment index of smaller element 
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]); 
        } 
    } 
    swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]); 
    return (i + 1); 
}

/* arr[] --> Array to be sorted, 
   low  --> Starting index, 
   high  --> Ending index */
void quickSort(char **arr, int low, int high) { 
    if (low < high) { 
        /* pi is partitioning index, arr[p] is now 
           at right place */
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high); 

        // Separately sort elements before 
        // partition and after partition 
        quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1); 
        quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high); 
    } 
} 

int main(){

   char *a = "abc";
   char *b = "cdf";
   swap(&a, &b);
   printf("a = %s, b= %s\n", a, b);
   char * data[10]={"cow", "goat", "dog", "sheep", "chicken", "duck", "bird","fish", "bee", "horse"};
   quickSort(data, 0, 9);
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%s, ", data[i]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

After sorting, you can using your searching algorithm.

Comment: There is no reason to post your own sorting algorithm in response to this question, the standard library implementation of qsort is fine.

Comment: The question is edited during the time i updated the sorting code, so i do not know about the edition. This reason why i post my own sorting algorithm. So down vote is not fair for me, i think. I just try to help him sorting the data before searching.

Comment: The down vote is solely because you recommend your code over using the standard library, nothing to do with the OP's edit.

Comment: it's a nice sorting algorithm.